# Finding all the links inside a Visual Studio project via powershell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

I've do due some mantainance on a Visual Studio Solution and in the specific task I've to remove all the linked files and replace them with a shared assembly. I wish to have a list of all the link files in the separate vs project and I've tried with no luck to use powershell.
Consider this portion of a proj file

```
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="..\XXX.Services.Inquiry\src\DTO\AccountingEntry.cs">
  <Link>DTO\AccountingEntry.cs</Link>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="..\XXX.Services.Inquiry\src\DTO\BalanceDetailItem.cs">
  <Link>DTO\BalanceDetailItem.cs</Link>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="..\XXX.Services.Inquiry\src\DTO\BalancesForCurrencyItem.cs">
  <Link>DTO\BalancesForCurrencyItem.cs</Link>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="..\XXX.Services.Inquiry\src\DTO\HistoricalCashSaleFlow.cs">
  <Link>DTO\HistoricalCashSaleFlow.cs</Link>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="..\XXX.Services.Inquiry\src\DTO\HistoricalChangeBceItem.cs">
  <Link>DTO\HistoricalChangeBceItem.cs</Link>
</Compile>
```

I've been able to find the Compile node using

```
$xx = $proj.GetElementsByTagName("Compile")
```

Now I wish to have the input in the form

```
AccountEntry | ..\XXX.Services.Inquiry\src\DTO\AccountingEntry.cs
BalanceDetailItem | ..\XXX.Services.Inquiry\src\DTO\BalanceDetailItem.cs
```

and so on...

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse XML as follows:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $PathToCsprojFile
```

Then you can access all the nodes e.g. as:

```
$xml.Project.ItemGroup.Compile.Include | Where-Object { $_ -eq 'MyIncludeFile.cs'}
```